# Angular cancel observable and call service method again?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a service method that needs to call itself again if there are error conditions in the data returned.

Here's my simplified service call, omitting types, etc...

```js
class LibraryService {

  translate(translationRequest): Observable<ITranslation> {
    this.httpClient
        .post<string>(url, formData, { ... }
        .pipe(
          take(1),
          map(response => {
            if (response.errors) {
              // modify translationRequest
              const updatedTranslationRequest = {
                ...,
              };

              this.translate(updatedTranslationRequest);
            }

            return response;
          }),
          map(response => ...),
        );
    }

}
```

What I need to do is cancel the observable if there are errors in the response, modify the request and call translate again.

What's currently happening is the next map operation is called and the `translate` function is not called again, or if it *is* being called, it's getting swallowed as I never see an additional network request.

How can I make the translate method start over?

Comment: RxJs retry and retryWhen are your friends..

Comment: You should use `retryWhen` https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen

Comment: How can you handle multiple cases with `retryWhen` though? I have other code that throws, which is picked up by the subscriber.'s `catchError`

Comment: When I add `retryWhen` to my service call, it overrides `catchError` on the subscriber

Comment: If you don't want to retry on any specific `Error`..you just simply `throw Error` from `retryWhen` and that will be caught by `catchError`.I will suggest you check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwnknr?file=app%2Frxjs-utils.ts.

Comment: `Example 2: Customizable retry with increased duration` in  learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retrywhen

Comment: interesting. I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demonstration

```
const translatePostMethod = interval(1000); //Demonstration purpose only
const translateSubscription = translatePostMethod.pipe(
  mergeMap((val) => {
    if (val > 5) {
      //If error happened
      return throwError('Error!');
    }
    return of(val);
  }),
  //retry another time on error
  retry(1)
);
const subscribe = translateSubscription.subscribe({
  next: (val) => console.log('-----', val),
  error: (val) => console.log(`${val}: Retried 1 times then quit!`),
});
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3yocmx?file=index.ts) link to get your hands dirty